# Configuring the mysql server

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, mysql5

I have a mysql server installed in RHEL 6 system with 128 GB of Ram and 16 Cores. i am running 4 websites with quite heavy queries having big joins and sortings. Please suggest me a good configuration for my my.cnf file. Below is my current configuration.. I am having mostly innodb tables in my schema...

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
max_connections = 2500
tmp_table_size = 512M
binlog_cache_size =  32768
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2097152
innodb_file_per_table =1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8388608
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
local_infile = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
key_buffer_size = 50G
read_buffer_size = 2M
thread_stack = 262144
query_cache_size =512M
query_cache_limit = 512M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 8M
query_cache_type = 1
thread_cache_size = 100
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50G
table_cache = 4096
read_rnd_buffer_size = 524288
sort_buffer_size = 16M
join_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 64M
thread_concurrency = 32
```

Comment: What version of MySQL 5 are you using ? If you are not sure, please run `SELECT VERSION();` in mysql or `mysqld --version` from the command line.

Comment: What is your main bottleneck?